# Kubernetes nginx-ingress with cloudflare tunnel

Tags: kubernetes, cloudflare, nlb, ingress-nginx, cloudflare-argo

I have a kubernetes cluster with ingress setup as a ingress-nginx. The load balancer used is NLB(Netwwork Load Balancer) and is internet-facing. Is there a way to setup cloudflared tunnel with the ingress based on the domain associated with the ingress. I have TLS termination enabled on load balancer.

example

demo-app -> ingress -> demo.test.com

I did setup cloudflare tunnel, but however it does not work as expected, either fails or the connection is never established.
Is there any particular way to achieve this. What changes needs to be done either on NLB side or on cloudflare tunnel side.